# Using ModelBuilder to generate multiple buffers based on multiple attribute fields for range of features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, buffer

I'm trying to create a multi ring buffer for features in a single feature class. Each feature has 5 different buffer values, and each feature may or may not be present when the tool is run.

Currently, my approach is to use select layer by attribute, copy features and dissolve on SlopeType+VegType to create a simplified source file to run the buffers from.

The resulting feature class attribute table looks something like this.

[image]

I'm trying to use an iterator (Iterate Feature Selection) to step through each feature and then a Get Field Value in each Buffer Field, then I run a Pairwise Buffer on each of those values. This is where I run into trouble. The output buffers are only taking the last value in the table for the given Buffer field. I.e. Buffer1 is applying a 20m buffer to all features. I know it has something to do with inline variables but I can't work out how to use them in a way that gives me a single feature per buffer type.

The intended output is a merged set of buffers per Buffer attribute field that respect the various buffer distances for each feature.

Comment: Instead of Get Field Value, why not just pass the field name "Buffer 1" to the Pairwise Buffer tool as the distance argument? That should use the appropriate value for each feature.

Comment: Are you aware of the [multi-ring buffer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/multiple-ring-buffer.htm) tool?